# How to make couple of JSON Get request Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is an interesting question. I'm using a simple JSON Get request to get all the competetions according to date, and show result as a list.

the JSON response is kind of :

```
[
{
"id":33
"competition":565 
},
{
"id":66
"competition":345
}
]
```

Then I should make another json request to get the name of each json item :

```
myserver.com/{id}
```

which look like :

```
{
"name":"Serie A"
}
```

I want to show a list of all the names of the competetions I have on the first json request according to date.

here is my angular js code for showing the list of a simple JSON request :

```
<div ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="m in matches">
    {{ m.id }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>



<script>
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://Myserver.com/matches?date=2015-05-19")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.matches = response;});
</script>
```

Comment: You could make another request within the callback. Even better is to just include the name on the server side, so it will be included in the first request

Comment: I don't have access to the server, even to make another request on the callback How can I manage to show all the names on a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the matches and get the names with a new call:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://myserver.com/matches?date=2015-05-19")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.matches = response;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                setName($scope.matches, i);
            }
        });

    var setName = function (matches, index) {
        $http.get("http://myserver.com/" + matches[index].id)
            .success(function (response) {
                matches[index].name = response.name;
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will first fetch all the competitions and then using their `id`s it will fetch `names` all the events parallely. it will give all the competition with details in one go only.

**Warning**: If you have large numbers of all competition then it will make same number of calls to get competition details all of them.

```js
app.service('competition', function($http) {

  this.getAllCompetitions = function() {
    var baseUrl = 'http://Myserver.com';
    return $http.get(baseUrl + '/matches?date=2015-05-19')
      .then(function(allCompetitions) {
        /* sample `data`
          [
            {
                "id":33
                "competition":565 
            },
            {
                "id":66
                "competition":345
            }
          ]
        */
        var qArr = [];
        allCompetitions.forEach(function(competition, index) {
          var promise = $http.get(baseUrl + '/' + competition.id)
            .then(function(competitionDetail) {
              /* sample `competitionDetail`
                  {
                      "name":"Serie A"
                      "competition":565 
                  }
              */
              return {
                competitionDetail: competitionDetail,
                index: index
              };
            });
          aArr.push(promise);
        });

        return $q.all(qArr).then(function(listOfData) {
          listOfData.forEach(function(item) {
            allCompetitions[item.index] = angular.extend(allCompetitions[item.index], item.competitionDetail);
          });

          return allCompetitions;
        });
      });
  }

});
```